# How to specify function for on_failure with taskflow api

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-taskflow

How can I specify a function to run when a DAG fails using the taskflow api? Using the old style I am able to specify a function to run on_failure but I cannot figure out or find documentation to do it using the taskflow api with the DAG and task operators.

Comment: what is wrong with `'on_failure_callback': task_failure_func` ?

Comment: I have tried that but the function is never called.

Here is the task:
`@task(on_failure_callback=on_failure)
def error():
    raise ValueError('fail')
`

Here is the function I am trying to call:
`def on_failure():
    msg = pymsteams.connectorcard('webhook url')
    msg.title('DAG Exception')
    msg.text('\n')
    section = pymsteams.cardsection()
    section.title('Tellus Accounting DAG Failed')
    section.addImage('https://i.imgur.com/JHnIreh.png')
    msg.addSection(section)
    msg.send()
`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add code, rather than post in comments where it's much less readable and liable to deletion.

Answer (score 0):

The `@dag` decorator accepts all arguments that you can pass to when creating `DAG` instance, especially `on_failure_callback`. Same goes for `@task` decorator.

Also the `on_failure_callback` should be a function accepting `context` argument. In your example it's not, is there no `Error when executing on_failure_callback` error?